# How do I upload a 3D Facebook photo from Android?

Tags: facebook

iOS users can use portrait mode to upload 3D Facebook photos.
This uses a depth map + 2D photo to work.

PC users can do it by naming the files *.jpg & *_depth.jpg and uploading them as a a pair.

Google Pixel phones (and others with ports, see https://www.celsoazevedo.com/files/android/google-camera/ ) can autogenerate a depth map with the Lens Blur camera mode, which can be tested on http://depthy.me

HTC Evo 3D phones have stereo Side by Side pair, which can be converted to a depth map with Stereo Photo Maker on Windows

How can one upload a 3D photo to Facebook from Android?

Comment: Google recommends to place [depth map in XMP data](https://developers.google.com/depthmap-metadata/encoding) which then can be embedded into the JPEG image. However I don't know which apps and/or online services support such images.

Answer (score 0):

- Take Lens Blur photo in Google camera (ports work)
- Upload to depthy.me just to split depth map (optionally edit it)
- Use file manager to rename files to *.jpg and *_depth.jpg
- Use Firefox *Request Desktop Site* to load main Facebook new feed page
- Upload them *one at a time* (both together crashes)
- Post and view in main Facebook app
  [image: also works in dolphin]

https://youtu.be/DOb-CiURqJo